# Tinymce: uncaught type error: cannot read property 'getContent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce

The error is showing up at this line

```
var newLength = tinyMCE.editors[jQuery('#text').attr('id')].getContent({format : 'text'}).length;
```

It worked before, but it stopped working now. Please provide some suggestion. Thanks.

But in the case of below code, it works. it is working without errors.

if (jQuery('#text').html()) {

```
    data['Text'] = tinyMCE.editors[jQuery('#text').attr('id')].getContent({format : 'html'}).replace(/'/g, "\\'");
    data['TextNoTags'] = tinyMCE.editors[jQuery('#text').attr('id')].getContent({format : 'text'}).replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  }
  else {
    data['Text'] = "";
    data['TextNoTags'] = "";
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the element is on the page? Because it looks like there is no area with the id '#text'

Comment: other scripts with the same id are working on the page. so, couldnt understand where the issues is? it shows the same error with all changes.

Comment: Where did you get that code? Because I can't find anything like it online. I can find references to `tinyMCE. activeEditor`, but not `tinyMCE.editors` where the array is accessed like this.

Comment: It is the preexisting code done by somebody else who is no more here. I am solving the bug now. I also checked but didnt get a single reference online.

Comment: Try to supply more information, like the contents of the `tinyMCE.editors` object, when is this part of the code executed etc.

Comment: I tried already by tinyMCE.activeEditor, but didnt work